# Deducing pointer-to-member template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

Consider classes with member variables, like these:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    char b;
};

struct B {
    double c;
    bool d;
};
```

Is it possible to declare a template class that accepts as its template
argument a pointer-to-member-object to any one of the members declared 
in the above classes?
A class that accepts a generic pointer-to-member-object could be
declared and used as follows:

```
template<typename Class, typename Type, Type (Class::*Member)>
struct Magic
{ };

// Usage:
typedef Magic<A, int, &A::a> MagicWithA_a;
```

Unfortunately it is quite cumbersome having to pass in the `Class` and 
`Type` template arguments every time to make the final pointer work.

Is there any way to have these arguments deduced by partial specialization,
for example? That is, how can the `Magic` class be declared to make the
below definitions work?

```
typedef Magic<&B::c> MagicWithB_c;
typedef Magic<&A::b> MagicWithA_b;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With C++17 you can use `auto` non-type template parameter:

```
template<auto p_member>
struct Magic
{ };
```

Before C++17 only the longer variant that you've implemented would work.

Comment: Accepted as this is the exact answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can shorten it somewhat with specializations, yes. And if you don't mind resorting to macros you can have almost the syntax you want with [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11). First, a primary template specialization:

```
template<typename T, T pm>
struct MagicImpl; // Undefined for most types
```

Then a partial specialization for pointers to members, where we can freely add the parameters we wish to be deduced:

```
template<class Class, typename Type>
struct MagicImpl<Type Class::*, Type (Class::*Member)> {
};
```

And finally, we need to employ `decltype` to get the pointer to member type out of the pointer-to-member expression, which we hide behind the aforementioned macro:

```
#define MAGIC(...) MagicImpl<decltype(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__>
```

And you can use it as follows:

```
typedef MAGIC(&B::c) MagicWithB_c;
typedef MAGIC(&A::b) MagicWithA_b;
```