# Compact way to deduce extra template parameter types for pointer-to-member template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

Note: this question is largely academic.

We can use a pointer-to-member as a template parameter in a class template, but if the "dependant" types are not known we must declare all of them as template parameters. For examples:

```cpp
// Our template operates with a "pointer to member", but it's generic for
// both the type of the member value itself, as well as the owner type of
// which the value is a member.
template <class T, class V, V T::*memptr>
struct Foo {};
```

In this case we must include `T`, `V` as template parameters if the template functionality is generic over these types. Usage of this template seems rather verbose, however:

```cpp
struct Bar {int a;};
struct Baz {double a;};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // The first two parameters "Bar, int" are kinda redundant
  Foo<Bar, int, &Bar::a> foo1;
  // Same here with Baz, double
  Foo<Baz, double, &Baz::a> foo2;
}
```

In particular the template parameter `&Bar::a` is a non-type parameter whose type is `int &Bar::*`. Thus, it seems that `T=Bar, V=int` is quite obvious.

**Is there a syntax, metaprogram, or construct that can be exploited so that we can instantiate the template with only `memptr=&Bar::a` and allow `T=Bar, V=int` to be deduced/inferred?**

Ideally we would instantiate the template with simply:

```cpp
Foo<&Bar::a> foo1;
Foo<&Baz::a> foo2;
```

But I can't seem to figure out a way to achieve this. I have a solution that utilizes a preprocessor macro:

```cpp
// This is an ugly metaprogram and macro to shorten-up usages of the template
template <class T, class V>
struct Step2 {
  template <V T::*memptr>
  struct Step3 {
    typedef Foo<T, V, memptr> Type;
  };
};

template <class T, class V>
Step2<T, V> step1(V T::*memptr);

#define FOO(T, MEMBER) decltype(step1(&T::MEMBER))::Step3<&T::MEMBER>::Type
```

Which can be used as:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // It seems that thre should be a more compact way to instantiate this
  // template. Indeed the macro does this, but macros are tough because they're
  // global names and it can make compiler errors really tough to comprehend.
  FOO(Bar, a) foo1;
  FOO(Baz, a) foo2;
}
```

But this does not seem like a problem that needs preprocessor macros as a solution.

Comment: if C++17 is not around. First solution seems more compact and it provides good readability about template arguments too then the second solution.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question: 
[Deducing pointer-to-member template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478886/deducing-pointer-to-member-template-arguments)

The answer from there is to lean on C++17 auto magic:

```cpp
template <auto p>
struct Foo {};
```